# How to upload artifacts from TeamCity to Nexus Pro

Tags: teamcity, nexus

Our TeamCity project currently produces a number of MSI files and wanted to upload the MSI files into our Nexus repository.

The MSI file is created by visual studio and no POM file is created as Maven is not used

Has anyone configured something similar to above and successfully transferred files from non java components in Nexus?

Comment: This article may help: https://support.sonatype.com/entries/22189106-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-

Comment: Did you find a way to do it, is there any tutorial ?